# creating stream to iterate over from string in Python

Tags: python, string, io

I want to create a stream from a string in Python so that it's equivalent to reading the string as if it's read from a text file. something like:

```
for line in open('myfile.txt'):
    print(line)
```

except the contents of 'myfile.txt' are stored in a string `s`. Is this the correct/best way to do it?

```
from io import StringIO

s = StringIO("a\t\b\nc\td\n")
for line in s:
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> I want to create a stream from a string in Python so that it's equivalent to reading the string as if it's read from a text file.
>
> ## Is this the correct/best way to do it?

Yes, unless you really do want it in a list.

If it is intended to be consumed line by line, the way you are doing it makes sense.

`StringIO()` creates a file-like object.

File objects have a method, `.readlines()`, which materialize the object as a list. Instead of materializing the data in a list, you can iterate over it, which is more memory light:

```
# from StringIO import StringIO # Python 2 import
from io import StringIO # Python 3 import

txt = "foo\nbar\nbaz"
```

Here we append each line *into* a list, so that we can demonstrate iterating over the file-like object and keeping a handle on the data. (More efficient would be `list(file_like_io)`.

```
m_1 = []
file_like_io = StringIO(txt)
for line in file_like_io:
    m_1.append(line)
```

and now:

```
>>> m_1
['foo\n', 'bar\n', 'baz']
```

you can return your io to any index point with `seek`:

```
>>> file_like_io.seek(0)
>>> file_like_io.tell() # where we are in the object now
0
```

### If you really want it in a list

`.readlines()` materializes the `StringIO` iterator as if one did `list(io)` - this is considered less preferable.

```
>>> m_2 = file_like_io.readlines()
```

And we can see that our results are the same:

```
>>> m_1 == m_2
True
```

Keep in mind that it is splitting after the newlines, preserving them in the text as well, so you'll get two newlines for every printed line, double-spacing on print.

Answer (score 0):

You could roll your own with a simple [generator function](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) like this:

```
def string_stream(s, separators="\n"):
    start = 0
    for end in range(len(s)):
        if s[end] in separators:
            yield s[start:end]
            start = end + 1
    if start < end:
        yield s[start:end+1]
```

Example usage:

```
>>> stream = string_stream("foo\tbar\nbaz\n", "\t\n")
>>> for s in stream:
...     print(s)
...
foo
bar
baz
```

[cStringIO](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html#module-cStringIO) may be faster (I haven't tested), but this would give you flexibility in defining/consuming separators.